# mergesort algorithm misunderstanding

Tags: python, algorithm, mergesort

Python student here,

I have been studying up on basic algorithms and I am having some trouble fully understanding `MergeSort`.
I believe I understand the divide and conquer approach, how namespaces are created within each loop cycle, and how the algorithm splits up the elements. Where I get a bit confused is in how it reassembles/merges the elements, successively taking on the sorted values.

I think I understand everything from results line 21 to 37. i.e. how `nlist` is transformed to `[27, 43]`.
My specific question is regarding `results` line 38 and how `righthalf` which was `[43, 27]` at result line 21, takes on the value of `nlist` which is `[27, 43]` (`results` line 38).

As I do not see any variable assignment of `nlist` to `righthalf,`

i.e. `righthalf = nlist` is not in the code flow between 'results' lines 37 & 38

MergeSort Algorithm (with diagnostic print statements):

```
def mergeSort(nlist):
    print("Splitting ", nlist)
    if len(nlist) > 1:
        mid = len(nlist) // 2
        lefthalf = nlist[: mid]
        righthalf = nlist[mid :]
        print('wow', 'lefthalf', lefthalf)
        mergeSort(lefthalf)
        print('this is the right1', righthalf)
        mergeSort(righthalf)
        print('this is the right2', righthalf)
        i = j = k = 0

        print("cool")
        while i < len(lefthalf) and j < len(righthalf):
            if lefthalf[i] < righthalf[j]:
                print('bot', 'k', 'i', 'j', 'lefthalf', 'righthalf', k, i, j, lefthalf, righthalf)
                nlist[k] = lefthalf[i]
                print('nlist[k]', nlist[k], nlist)
                i = i + 1
            else:
                print('me')
                nlist[k] = righthalf[j]
                print('k', 'nlist[k]', k, nlist[k], nlist)
                print(righthalf)
                j = j + 1

            k = k + 1

        while i < len(lefthalf):
            print('cot', 'k', 'i', 'lefthalf', k, i, lefthalf)
            nlist[k] = lefthalf[i]
            print('nlist[k]', nlist[k], nlist)
            i = i + 1
            k = k + 1

        while j < len(righthalf):
            print('dot', 'k', 'j', 'righthalf', k, j, righthalf)
            nlist[k] = righthalf[j]
            print('nlist[k]', nlist[k], nlist)
            j = j + 1
            k = k + 1

    print("Merging ", nlist)

nlist = [14, 46, 43, 27, 57, 41, 45, 21, 70]
mergeSort(nlist)
print(nlist)
```

Results

```
1     Splitting  [14, 46, 43, 27, 57, 41, 45, 21, 70]
2     wow lefthalf [14, 46, 43, 27]
3     Splitting  [14, 46, 43, 27]
4     wow lefthalf [14, 46]
5     Splitting  [14, 46]
6     wow lefthalf [14]
7     Splitting  [14]
8     Merging  [14]
9     yah righthalf [46]
10    this is the right1 [46]
11    Splitting  [46]
12    Merging  [46]
13    this is the right2 [46]
14    cool
15    bot k i j lefthalf righthalf 0 0 0 [14] [46]
16    nlist[k] 14 [14, 46]
17    dot k j righthalf 1 0 [46]
18    nlist[k] 46 [14, 46]
19    Merging  [14, 46]
20    yah righthalf [43, 27]
21    this is the right1 [43, 27]
22    Splitting  [43, 27]
23    wow lefthalf [43]
24    Splitting  [43]
25    Merging  [43]
26    yah righthalf [27]
27    this is the right1 [27]
28    Splitting  [27]
29    Merging  [27]
30    this is the right2 [27]
31    cool
32    me
33    k nlist[k] 0 27 [27, 27]
34    [27]
35    cot k i lefthalf 1 0 [43]
36    nlist[k] 43 [27, 43]
37    Merging  [27, 43]
38    this is the right2 [27, 43]
39    cool
40    bot k i j lefthalf righthalf 0 0 0 [14, 46] [27, 43]
41    nlist[k] 14 [14, 46, 43, 27]
42    me
43    k nlist[k] 1 27 [14, 27, 43, 27]
44    [27, 43]
45    me
46    k nlist[k] 2 43 [14, 27, 43, 27]
47    [27, 43]
48    cot k i lefthalf 3 1 [14, 46]
49    nlist[k] 46 [14, 27, 43, 46]
50    Merging  [14, 27, 43, 46]
51    yah righthalf [57, 41, 45, 21, 70]
52    this is the right1 [57, 41, 45, 21, 70]
53    Splitting  [57, 41, 45, 21, 70]
54    wow lefthalf [57, 41]
55    Splitting  [57, 41]
56    wow lefthalf [57]
57    Splitting  [57]
58    Merging  [57]
59    yah righthalf [41]
60    this is the right1 [41]
61    Splitting  [41]
62    Merging  [41]
63    this is the right2 [41]
64    cool
65    me
66    k nlist[k] 0 41 [41, 41]
67    [41]
68    cot k i lefthalf 1 0 [57]
69    nlist[k] 57 [41, 57]
70    Merging  [41, 57]
71    yah righthalf [45, 21, 70]
72    this is the right1 [45, 21, 70]
73    Splitting  [45, 21, 70]
74    wow lefthalf [45]
75    Splitting  [45]
76    Merging  [45]
77    yah righthalf [21, 70]
78    this is the right1 [21, 70]
79    Splitting  [21, 70]
80    wow lefthalf [21]
81    Splitting  [21]
82    Merging  [21]
83    yah righthalf [70]
84    this is the right1 [70]
85    Splitting  [70]
86    Merging  [70]
87    this is the right2 [70]
88    cool
89    bot k i j lefthalf righthalf 0 0 0 [21] [70]
90    nlist[k] 21 [21, 70]
91    dot k j righthalf 1 0 [70]
92    nlist[k] 70 [21, 70]
93    Merging  [21, 70]
94    this is the right2 [21, 70]
95    cool
96    me
97    k nlist[k] 0 21 [21, 21, 70]
98    [21, 70]
99    bot k i j lefthalf righthalf 1 0 1 [45] [21, 70]
100   nlist[k] 45 [21, 45, 70]
101   dot k j righthalf 2 1 [21, 70]
102   nlist[k] 70 [21, 45, 70]
103   Merging  [21, 45, 70]
104   this is the right2 [21, 45, 70]
105   cool
106   me
107   k nlist[k] 0 21 [21, 41, 45, 21, 70]
108   [21, 45, 70]
109   bot k i j lefthalf righthalf 1 0 1 [41, 57] [21, 45, 70]
110   nlist[k] 41 [21, 41, 45, 21, 70]
111   me
112   k nlist[k] 2 45 [21, 41, 45, 21, 70]
113   [21, 45, 70]
114   bot k i j lefthalf righthalf 3 1 2 [41, 57] [21, 45, 70]
115   nlist[k] 57 [21, 41, 45, 57, 70]
116   dot k j righthalf 4 2 [21, 45, 70]
117   nlist[k] 70 [21, 41, 45, 57, 70]
118   Merging  [21, 41, 45, 57, 70]
119   this is the right2 [21, 41, 45, 57, 70]
120   cool
121   bot k i j lefthalf righthalf 0 0 0 [14, 27, 43, 46] [21, 41, 45, 57, 70]
122   nlist[k] 14 [14, 46, 43, 27, 57, 41, 45, 21, 70]
123   me
124   k nlist[k] 1 21 [14, 21, 43, 27, 57, 41, 45, 21, 70]
125   [21, 41, 45, 57, 70]
126   bot k i j lefthalf righthalf 2 1 1 [14, 27, 43, 46] [21, 41, 45, 57, 70]
127   nlist[k] 27 [14, 21, 27, 27, 57, 41, 45, 21, 70]
128   me
129   k nlist[k] 3 41 [14, 21, 27, 41, 57, 41, 45, 21, 70]
130   [21, 41, 45, 57, 70]
131   bot k i j lefthalf righthalf 4 2 2 [14, 27, 43, 46] [21, 41, 45, 57, 70]
132   nlist[k] 43 [14, 21, 27, 41, 43, 41, 45, 21, 70]
133   me
134   k nlist[k] 5 45 [14, 21, 27, 41, 43, 45, 45, 21, 70]
135   [21, 41, 45, 57, 70]
136   bot k i j lefthalf righthalf 6 3 3 [14, 27, 43, 46] [21, 41, 45, 57, 70]
137   nlist[k] 46 [14, 21, 27, 41, 43, 45, 46, 21, 70]
138   dot k j righthalf 7 3 [21, 41, 45, 57, 70]
139   nlist[k] 57 [14, 21, 27, 41, 43, 45, 46, 57, 70]
140   dot k j righthalf 8 4 [21, 41, 45, 57, 70]
141   nlist[k] 70 [14, 21, 27, 41, 43, 45, 46, 57, 70]
142   Merging  [14, 21, 27, 41, 43, 45, 46, 57, 70]
143   [14, 21, 27, 41, 43, 45, 46, 57, 70]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka! After an ungodly number of hours spent on this...i have found it.

When a mutable object(in this case a list) is passed into a function as an argument ('righthalf'), and that argument is recursively mutated ('nlist'), the argument is also mutated and this change is reflected outside the function. This represents the "call by object reference" property of python.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/is-python-call-by-reference-or-call-by-value/

In this specific situation

- 'righthalf' - [43, 27] was passed into the mergesort function as an argument,
- the recursive function received it as 'nlist'
- 'nlist' was mutated into [27, 43] within a recursive function,
- As both point to the same reference location in memory, 'righthalf'
  is mutated as well and there is no need for the traditional assignment

```
    righthalf = nlist
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Indeed your implementation of `mergeSort` performs in place sorting. It is quite common to see Python implementations that construct and return a sorted array from their argument, sometimes incorrectly returning the argument itself if its length is less than 2.

Comment: @chqrlie Interesting. This raises a question for me though. If the length is "less than 2" why is returning the argument itself incorrect, as you suggest. Since an array with 1 or 0 elements should return the same result as its sorted version. i.e. sorting the array [5] will always give [5]...Yes?

Comment: It is a matter of consistency: the function should either always sort in place, as yours does, or always return a new array with the same elements appropriately sorted. Returning the argument array when it has less than 2 elements breaks this prerequisite and may produce hard to find bugs if the calling code assumes the sorted array is different from the argument. This assumption might be implicit: for example the elements from the sorted array might be removed one at a time, with a side effect in the original array only in special cases, causing other inconsistent  behavior.

Comment: @chqrlie I see. That makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Assume you have two sorted lists in front of you. To obtain the merged list, you take the smallest of the two elements at the head of both lists, and repeat until you exhaust both lists.

```
[*14, 27, 43, 46]
[ 21, 41, 45, 57, 70]

[ 27, 43, 46]
[*21, 41, 45, 57, 70]

[*27, 43, 46]
[ 41, 45, 57, 70]

[ 43, 46]
[*41, 45, 57, 70]

[*43, 46]
[ 45, 57, 70]

[ 46]
[*45, 57, 70]

[*46]
[ 57, 70]

[]
[*57, 70]

[]
[*70]

[]
[]
```

Comment: It might help if you added the destination list to show where the starred item is going:  `-->[]`, `-->[14]`, `-->[14, 21]`, etc.  You could also point out that at each stage you only need to compare the two items at the head of the lists.

Comment: Thanks. I understand how the minimum 0th index between two sorted ('lefthalf' and 'righthalf') list is taken and used to build up the final list. I just dont fully understand how we got each of those sorted list. I get how we break an initial list down into 1 element each. I get how we can build a main list ('nlist') by taking the min 0th element between left and right. But in the logic it seems the variables lefthalf or righthalf are assigned the value of the sorted list one is building. I'm just not clear on where that assignment is happening. ps I edited my initial question for clarity

Comment: @lolababa02 The assignment to `righthalf` happens _every time you recurse_ - you call `mergesort()` on one half, one half of which again ends up in `righthalf` with `righthalf = nlist[mid:]`

Comment: @pjs: there was no nice place to put the resulting list. I said "you take the smallest of the two elements at the head of both lists".

Comment: @Mathias Perfect! This is exactly what i was thinking. Question though. If the assingment happens when you recurse again, i would expect to hit the print statement ("wow", "lefthalf") in Algorithm line 7. I dont. i.e.in 'results' line 37 i get the reordered list (merging, "nlist"), the next line 38 simple has righthalf now reordered. There is No recursion btw ln 37 & 38. Nor is it obvious how "righthalf" got the values of "nlist" Thanks

Comment: @Yves Thank you for your answer! I believe my confusion stems from the the assignment portion of the logic (previous comment).